# Send an Email to a Static Email Address based on a Trigger Word in a Column of a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, gmail

I have the following code, but my 'if' argument to send the 'message' array  doesn't seem to execute for every row that has ALERT as the text in col[19].  Rather, only one email is being sent each time the script is run, even though there are several ALERTs in col[19].

```
function analyzeAlerts() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 4;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 30;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 30)

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (i in data) {
var col = data[i];
var subject = "Upcoming Bill Alerts";
var message = "The bill for "+col[13]+" Invoice #:"+col[11]+" for $"+col[12]+" is due on "+col[14];
if (col[19]="ALERT") {
MailApp.sendEmail("hello@world.com", subject, message);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure what language this is but = is not == in all languages and are you sure they are all upper case ALERT?   Welcome to stack please add a tag for the language you are working with.

Comment: DalmTo. Thank you, this is the Google Script that is built in to the Google Apps (i think that it is based on JavaScript?).  The ALERT is in all caps in the spreadsheet.